# Saving File in php through URL

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I have a function which is supposed to save a file to my server, the function requires two parameters the file url and the filename where which it will be saved with in the database

```
function saveFile($url, $filename){

    $location = "http://138.90.30.311/docs/";
    $ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file_path = $location.''.$filename.'.'.$ext;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen($file_path, 'wb');  //Error here (line 16)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);  //Error here (line 17)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);        
}
```

Example of the parameters passed in would be

```
filename = 14426
url = http://u.goal.com/269000/269085_hp_thumb.jpg
```

I got it work once but it doesn't seem to save the file anymore and I'm getting 3 errors

```
Warning: fopen(http://138.90.30.311/docs/14426.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 16

Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 17
```

After the second error I get alot of junk echoed back to the browser

```
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write a file to a website (with HTTP), as the error message says. If you think about it, this is a good thing, otherwise I could write files to your website without your permission!

The file path you give to `fopen` (specifically `$location`) needs to be a plain file path somewhere on the server the PHP is running on.

Comment: What I want to do is take a file passed in by the url and save in that location

Comment: If the location to save to is on the same server the PHP runs on, just give the directory path, not `http://...`. If not, you will need to use something like FTP to upload it with.

Comment: I've tried that and still get the same error, I've now changed ownership of the folder to Admin as well but still the same error.